# In creating a comment, getting "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times" for no apparent reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have User via devise, Post, and Comment. On show for each post, I want to show comment.

The problem is that I keep getting "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times..." error when I create a comment. Now, this is a symptom and not the cause I want to address. When this error is called, the redirect_to failure is highlighted, meaning the comment is not created.

How can I fix this? Also, though it's secondary, what might fix the render and/or redirect... error?

Another detail: When I use :id instead of :post_id in comments controller, it throws an error (Couldn't find Post without an ID). When I use :post_id instead of :id in posts controller show (to feed the view form), it throws an error (Couldn't find Post without an ID)

**UPDATE**:
In my comment.rb and user.rb, I had belongs_to user and has_many comments. In addition to user having many posts and posts having many comments. I deleted those user-comment connections. Then I replaced in the show.html.erb @post, @comment with @post, @post.comments.build. Now it seems to save to the database. But it still throws the "render and/or..." error. How can I fix this?

From my list of posts, I go to show.html.erb via post_path(post.id). But when I use the same in the show.html.erb to remain there, it says "undefined local variable or method `post'" So I switched to @post, which then throws the above error.

Also I'm not clear about this no matter how much I read the documentation. Is my User connected to Comment even if I don't make that connection explicit in the models and in the database (my comment has post_id but no user_id)? How?

posts controller show:

```rb
    def show
        @user = current_user
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @comment = @post.comments.new
    end
```

show.html.erb:

```rb
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

comments controller in full:

```rb
    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.new
        render :template => 'posts/show'
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.new
        render :template => 'posts/show'
    end

    def create

        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)

        render :template => 'posts/show'

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: "Success!~"
        else 
            redirect_to post_path(@post), alert: "Failure!" 
        end

    end

    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
        end
```

routes

```rb
  resources :users do
    resources :posts, shallow: true do
      resources :comments, shallow: true
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within create action of the comments controller, you have called

```
render :template => 'posts/show'
```

and afterwards redirected to `post_path`.

As error message says, you can't both render and redirect within same action.

It's not entirely clear what are you trying to accomplish, but my guess is that you can just simply remove the `render` call.

EDIT:

If your comments table has `post_id` foreign key, that means that your Comment model should also specify `belongs_to :post`, also using the same foreign key, your Post model should have 'has_many :posts'.

I'll make couple of assumption regarding your schema, but I believe you want this:

```rb
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  has_one :user, through: :post
end

# app/models/user.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Notice has_one through association, that will allow you to do the following:

```
Comment.find(id).user
```

Which will return will return user record referenced by `user_id` column in posts table.

Comment: Thank you! If you could please also answer this, I'd appreciate it, but if not, I will just post it as a separation question. "Also I'm not clear about this no matter how much I read the documentation. Is my User connected to Comment even if I don't make that connection explicit in the models and in the database (my comment has post_id but no user_id)? How?

Comment: Edited my answer, it was too long for comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I have upvoted the answer (although it says it won't show publicly since I have a very small reputation). One more question: Would this apply when other users comment on my post -- could I still associate that particular user with their comment (I plan to show their name next to their comments)?

Comment: The most logical approach would be to have `user_id` foreign key on comment. Them have a `belongs_to :user` within Comment model and `has_many :comments` defined in User model.

When creating comment, in CommentsController, you'd use currently authenticated user (usually `current_user`) and associate it with the comment record. `@post.comments.create { user: current_user }`.